Connecting to service on host port from inside Docker container, ping works (address resolves) but telnet fails
On the host I check connectivity to the serivice via the port:
telnet 127.0.0.1 30305
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

Now I want to connect from inside a container...
I start the container like this:
docker run -it --add-host james:host-gateway  --rm alpine /bin/ash 

then install telnet like this:
apk update
apk add busybox-extras

check that the special host-ip resolves, like this:
ping james
PING james (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms

however:
telnet james 30305

Simply hangs forever
What can be the issue?
I know it is a Docker networking issue, because I ran the 30305 service on a totally different server, and it connects fine, the issue is ONLY when the service is running on the SAME machine as Docker.
I'm assuming this special Docker host-ip trick is all local and doesn't touch the firewall.

Maybe your service only listen from 127.0.0.1 host so that connect from docker container failed since the mapped host is 172.17.0.1. You can try use port-mapping for docker so that you can access to your server's service from localhost(127.0.0.1)
docker run -p 30305:30305 -it --rm alpine /bin/ash 

